# Make request to SOAP endpoint using axios

Tags: xml, reactjs, post, soap, axios

I need to make request to SOAP endpoint using `axios` in my `React` application. Hence I need to pass xml data in request and receive xml data in response.

I have used the axios post with json data but how do I use the same for xml?  PFB the code I am using for the same, but it does not work.

JSON post request:

```
var xmlData = <note>
<to>Tove</to>
<from>Jani</from>
<heading>Reminder</heading>
<body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>

var config = {
  headers: {'Content-Type': 'text/xml'}
};

axios.post('/save', xmlData, config);
```

Please share if you have any experience with this, TIA.

Comment: Did you try this: `headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/xml'}`

Comment: @DrunkDevKek : Yes I did, did not work!

Comment: Are you receiving any errors? Maybe you can expand on what you mean by that it does not work.

Comment: I am away till Monday, will share th error log when back! Thanks .

Comment: Looks like your xmlData is wrong - it should be something like: <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:uploadwsdl">
      <soapenv:Header/>
      <soapenv:Body> etc.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

```
let xmls='<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"\
                            xmlns:web="http://www.webserviceX.NET/">\
            <soapenv:Header/>\
            <soapenv:Body>\
              <web:ConversionRate>\
                <web:FromCurrency>INR</web:FromCurrency>\
                <web:ToCurrency>USD</web:ToCurrency>\
              </web:ConversionRate>\
            </soapenv:Body>\
          </soapenv:Envelope>';

axios.post('http://www.webservicex.com/CurrencyConvertor.asmx?wsdl',
           xmls,
           {headers:
             {'Content-Type': 'text/xml'}
           }).then(res=>{
             console.log(res);
           }).catch(err=>{console.log(err)});
```

**This code help to make soap request**

Comment: good solutions and best answer. Thanks for answer here in stackoverflow

Comment: `{headers:
             {'Content-Type': 'text/xml' , 'SoapAction': 'blahblah'}
           }` Soap service may expect the soap action name in the header. You can get it from the WSDL . I got an issue with Soap action not found.

Comment: Its depends on how your server is handle the request you may need some extra header

Answer (score 14):

I used the answer of @Anuragh KP but with a SOAPAction header

```
axios.post('https://wscredhomosocinalparceria.facilinformatica.com.br/WCF/Soap/Emprestimo.svc?wsdl',
           xmls,
  {headers:
  {
    'Content-Type': 'text/xml',
    SOAPAction: 'http://schemas.facilinformatica.com.br/Facil.Credito.WsCred/IEmprestimo/CalcularPrevisaoDeParcelas'}
  }).then(res => {
    console.log(res)
  }).catch(err => {
    console.log(err.response.data)
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not using axios but I think it worth mentioning (it also rather new - 4 month at the time of answering) and solved my problem of calling SOAP from NodeJS: https://www.npmjs.com/package/soap

from the owners sample code:

```
  var soap = require('soap');
  var url = 'http://example.com/wsdl?wsdl';
  var args = {name: 'value'};
  soap.createClientAsync(url).then((client) => {
    return client.MyFunctionAsync(args);
  }).then((result) => {
    console.log(result);
  });
```

[url to code quote](https://www.npmjs.com/package/soap#:%7E:text=to%20disable%20it.-,soap.createClientAsync(url%5B%2C%20options%5D)%20%2D%20create%20a%20new%20SOAP%20client%20from%20a%20WSDL%20url.%20Also%20supports%20a%20local%20filesystem%20path,-.)

Comment: I am using the same, how ever I got an issue while doing the webpack. Did you got it ?

Comment: As far as I remember - not. Sorry I'm not working with this code anymore (changed employer).

Comment: Used axios and it got working. Thx

Answer (score 0):

Content-Type: application/soap+xml

If this error arrives, 'Transport level information does not match with SOAP Message namespace URI'.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).