# How to call soap webservice react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native, soap

I'm using `react-native`. I want to call `soap` web service. I think there isn't any library for soap request.

for example:

http://188.75.80.115:83/WebService1.asmx?op=getKey

Answer (score 0):

try [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) 
 
check out this answer 
[Make request to SOAP endpoint using axios](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49153096/3711273)