# React.js: Is it possible to call a SOAP web service using axios?

Tags: reactjs, soap, axios

I've had success when calling REST APIs when using axios

However, I need to call a SOAP web service from an old system

Is this possible using axios?

See sample code of my failed try:

```
callSoap() {
    let xmls =
      '<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">\
      <soap:Body>\
        <mtdGetTestNumber xmlns="http://test.com/services">\
          <AccountNumber>string</AccountNumber>\
          <RequestType>string</RequestType>\
        </mtdGetTestNumber>\
      </soap:Body>\
    </soap:Envelope>';

    let xmls2 =
      '<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">\
      <soap12:Body>\
        <mtdGetTestNumber xmlns="http://test.com/services">\
          <AccountNumber>string</AccountNumber>\
          <RequestType>string</RequestType>\
        </mtdGetTestNumber>\
      </soap12:Body>\
    </soap12:Envelope>';

    return axios.post(
      "http://192.254.1.2:8083/Service.asmx?op=mtdTestNumber",
      xmls,
      {
        headers: { "Content-Type": "text/xml" },
      }
    );
  }
```

This does not show any error when I return the error response.

Can someone enlighten me if this is possible?

Or should I create an API in backend (in my case its Spring Boot) to call the SOAP API then convert the xml response from SOAP to JSON and use that JSON to response to web?

TIA

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Make request to SOAP endpoint using axios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45974831/make-request-to-soap-endpoint-using-axios)

Comment: No, it didn't help

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible in axios.

See here where you have plenty of working examples -> [Make request to SOAP endpoint using axios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45974831/make-request-to-soap-endpoint-using-axios)

If you are struggling to get a response then check the server logs of the API you're trying to call.