# How can I call a SOAP webserver method in Vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, delphi, soap, webserver

I developed a small stand alone  webserver in Delphi. The procedure is as below:

```
function sum(a,b:string):string;stdcall;
begin
result:=a+b;
end;
```

How can I call it in Vue JS?

The web service URL is

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/soap/iservice1
```

the WSDL document:

```
<definitions xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
         xmlns:tns="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
         xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
         xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" name="Iservice1service"
         targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/">
<script/>
<message name="sum0Request">
    <part name="a" type="xs:string"/>
    <part name="b" type="xs:string"/>
</message>
<message name="sum0Response">
    <part name="return" type="xs:string"/>
</message>
<portType name="Iservice1">
    <operation name="sum">
        <input message="tns:sum0Request"/>
        <output message="tns:sum0Response"/>
    </operation>
</portType>
<binding name="Iservice1binding" type="tns:Iservice1">
    <binding xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" style="rpc"
             transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <operation name="sum">
        <operation xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" soapAction="urn:service1Intf-Iservice1#sum"
                   style="rpc"/>
        <input>
            <body xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" use="encoded"
                  encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="urn:service1Intf-Iservice1"/>
        </input>
        <output>
            <body xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" use="encoded"
                  encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="urn:service1Intf-Iservice1"/>
        </output>
    </operation>
</binding>
<service name="Iservice1service">
    <port name="Iservice1Port" binding="tns:Iservice1binding">
        <address xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" location="http://localhost:8080/soap/Iservice1"/>
    </port>
</service>
</definitions>
```

The vue codes:

```
    axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: webservice_url,
    data: data_to_send
  })
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

Now can you tell me what is the url (in vue
code) please?

Comment: Thanks. I see from the link that you sent: axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: webservice_url,
    data: data_to_send
  })
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });  so what should i put for url address to call my function(sum)?

Comment: Please add more details, how is your standalone webserver configured now? How did you add SOAP support to it?

Comment: The url of my webservice is: "localhost:8080/soap/iservice1". How can i put the method name in it? My method name is: sum. Like i said.

Comment: Does the service expose a WSDL document? In a WSDL document, all methods of the SOAP service are described. You can try to access it at localhost:8080/soap/iservice1?WSDL

Comment: If possible, include the WSDL document in your question.

Comment: The vue code is: axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: webservice_url,
    data: data_to_send
  })
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });  according to my webservice name that i said and according to that my procedure name is sum can you guide me that what value i must assing to webservice_url in vue?

Comment: You should [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/78243286/edit) your question with new details, not create a new question.  Code especially should always be added to a question where it can be formatted, not pasted in comments where it is much harder to read.

Comment: I edited the question. now you can see the WSDL doc in it.  now can you tell me the url name for using sum function in vuejs please? can you give me the vue codes?

Answer (score 0):

The HTTP endpoint for the SOAP service is

```
http://localhost:8080/soap/Iservice1
```

Here is how a SOAP request to invoke the "sum" operation on this service might look:

```
POST /soap/Iservice1 HTTP/1.1 
Host: localhost:8080 
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8 
SOAPAction: "urn:service1Intf-Iservice1#sum"

<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
  <soapenv:Header/>
  <soapenv:Body>
      <tem:sum>
         <tem:a>"string1"</tem:a>
         <tem:b>"string2"</tem:b>
      </tem:sum>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Note that the operation is not part of the URL, but passed in the SOAPAction header of the HTTP request.

Examples for Vue.js can be found here

- [Make request to SOAP endpoint using axios](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45974831/80901)

So the steps to invoke the sum operation using axios would be:

1. define constants for URL, request body, and request headers
   (Content-Type and SOAPAction)
2. invoke axios:

   axios({
   url: url,
   method: 'POST',
   data: soapRequestBody,
   headers: headers,
   })
   .then((response) => {
   this.response = response;
   console.log('Response', response);
   })
   .catch((error) => {
   console.log('Error', error);
   });

Comment: Very thanks of your guides. You do it by using xml type. Van you tell me how can do it for json type? In json type, how will be data variable? In json type, How can i give function name and parameters to data variable?

Comment: @Ham SOAP supports only XML data exchange. Your question is explicitly about a SOAP web service. For JSON, you may use REST web services.